# Python: Process large dictionary in chunks using multiprocessing

Tags: python, dictionary, split, multiprocessing

I am running a simulation with around  10 million unique dna sequences stored in a dictionary. And I need to process each sequence, which consists of going through the sequence letter by letter in groups of 5 (taking first 5 letters, shift index by one take another 5),
and processing it in a separate function. This takes quite a bit of time as I have it set up so it goes through each sequence one by one in a for loop.

What I am looking for is a way to split up the dictionary into approximately 20 chunks which I can use multiprocessing to process. Is there an easier way than just going through each key and filling up 20 dictionaries iteratively?

Comment: Note that this is only likely to be performant on POSIX systems, where `fork()` is available. On Windows, the arguments to subprocesses are pickled, which is likely to represent substantial overhead that could make multiprocessing *slower*.  If performance is absolutely critical, it might be wise to look into lower-level languages -- or, at least look into implementing the work loop in a lower-level language that you can invoke from Python.

Comment: @cdhowie This would be running on a unix based server with about 24 separate cpus so the overhead would be negligible for the large amount of processing that needs to take place

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `itertools.groupby`, this is a job for itertools. Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

All you have to do is specify the number of chunks or your case, `n = 5`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split the dictionary, all you need to do is to split the keys in 20 groups and work on the same dictionary. I think that is simpler.

Comment: I think this would be easiest as well. I also like @sihrc 's method so i'm combining it and using .keys() instead